# using random module to randomly pick from a list and execute something

Tags: python, random

i'm trying to get the program to randomly print a item from a list, then the program to ask the user to input some information where there is true/false conditions, and then return the user to the start where they can select a new 'track'

the problem im having is that, only 'listone' is being selected and its not a random list selection  thanks to all that help.

```
import random
questlist = ['questone', 'questtwo', 'questthree']
random.choice(questlist)


def start():
    print('Hi, welcome to the race track')
    pick = input('pick a track')
    displaytrack()


def displaytrack():
    tracks = ('track 1', 'track 2', 'track 3')
    print(tracks)



if 'questone':
    ans = input('how old are u')
    if ans == 3:
        print('Correct')
        print('Thanks for using')
        start()
    else:
            print('Incorrect')
            start()


if 'questtwo':
    ans = input('How nice are u')
    if ans == 'very':
        print('Correcterino')
        print('Thanks for using')
        start()
    else:
            print('Wrongerino')
            start()

if 'questthree':
    ans = input('How tall are u')
    if ans == 'pretty':
        print('sixfoot')
        print('Thanks for using')
        start()
    else:
            print('no feet')
            start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the output of the choice and use it in your conditional expressions:

```
choice = random.choice(questlist)
```

replace

```
if 'questone':
```

with

```
if choice == 'questone':
```

and so on, otherwise, the `if` expressions is just checking whether the string `'questone'` is `None`, and it will always evaluate to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of your current third line

```
PC_Choice = random.choice(questlist)
```

Then use: if PC_Choice == questone

like this:

```
if PC_Choice == 'questone':
    ans = input('how old are u')
    if ans == 3:
    print('Correct')
    print('Thanks for using')
    start()
else:
        print('Incorrect')
        start()
```

Then change the other two aswell this will make it give a random choice